# Why is firebug showing the same script multiple times

Tags: javascript, caching, firebug

I have a few scripts that are common among all html pages for my application.  Call this file commonfunctions.js.  Each html page will load it as you move around the application along with appending the last modification date for this js file (that's gotten from the server).  Firebug is adding the file every time to the list of loaded scripts as well as an eval/seq/# (where # is the number of times this file has been loaded starting at 7 for some reason). For example, if I have 3 pages called one.html, two.html, and three.html each with this line of code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="commonfunctions.js?mod=11/33/2012"></script>
```

If I were to go from one.html->two.html->one.html->three.html, Firebug would list the scripts loaded as:

> commonfunctions.js?mod=11/33/2012
>   commonfunctions.js?mod=11/33/2012/eval/seq/7
>   commonfunctions.js?mod=11/33/2012/eval/seq/8
>   commonfunctions.js?mod=11/33/2012/eval/seq/9

and so on as I visit the three pages more.

Why is this happening and is there a way to stop it?  I read that it could be that firebug will make its own url if it doesn't know the url due to an eval() or event attribute; however, these scripts are being loaded via regular tags.

I'm concerned because I'm not sure if this means the browser has now compiled and is executing or storing multiple copies of the same script--very wasteful in both conditions.

Comment: And you're sure the console clears the results from the previous pages when you move on to the next page etc.

Comment: @adeneo I'm not sure what you mean. the console just shows the ajax requests for each page.  The script menu is where I went to see the laoded scripts.  When I move on to the next page, the previous page's loaded commonfunctions.js script is still there and the new one is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script may have been loaded via script tag, but somewhere within commonfunctions.js a call to `eval()`has been made. Or three, obviously.

Comment: I just looked and there are 9 calls to eval in commonfunctions.js.  None load a new script however.  Could this be the reason that each new visit to a page containing commonfunctions.js adds a new script to firebug?

Comment: You are absolutely right. As soon as one of those evals is called Firebug shows a new script. Nothing to worry about.